Git pull on main branch merges in other newly created branches automatically
How can I prevent situation when on Pull, code changes done in other branches are merged into current branch? This caused few headaches already where each time head needs to be reset to what's on remote via hard reset.
PS C:\Users\user\repos\PyStorm> git checkout develop
Switched to branch 'develop'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/develop'.
PS C:\Users\user\repos\PyStorm> git pull
remote: Azure Repos
remote: Found 14 objects to send. (61 ms)
Unpacking objects: 100% (14/14), 4.42 KiB | 65.00 KiB/s, done.
From https://url/_git/PyStorm
 * [new branch]        story/1516106-data-insertion -> origin/story/1516106-data-insertion
Fast-forwarding to: 52b68e55c4ec4ba429e8bbd400acd86ce09ca349
Trying simple merge with ad812a46ea21b87c71cc3ce624db9f6a52ee790d
Merge made by the 'octopus' strategy.
 ConfigFiles/TestUsers.json                  |  4 ++
 Tests/LegacyQuickRegression/TestsQRPXHub.py | 20 +++++++++-
 pipelines/LogAnalyticsPOC.yml               | 58 +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 3 files changed, 80 insertions(+), 2 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 pipelines/LogAnalyticsPOC.yml
PS C:\Users\user\repos\PyStorm> git pull
Already up to date.
PS C:\Users\user\repos\PyStorm> git status
On branch develop
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/develop' by 4 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
PS C:\Users\user\repos\PyStorm> 


What's the branch's pull config? (git config --get branch.develop.merge)

That'll be > refs/heads/develop

Okay, so the config is as expected, but the result (octopus merge) is not.

This is truly bizarre, and feels like a bug to me. But yet another reason to never use git pull! (I'm a fan of exclusively using git fetch and then doing either merges or rebases as I deem appropriate in each situation.)

The suggestion from joanis is worth trying. On your local machine, reset hard to back before the merge. Then say git fetch; git merge origin/develop and see whether things go better.

Do you reckon this issue with our setup or a bug? What's the recommended steps to fix issue instead of work around?
